# What happens when I provide liquidity for a small market cap token?

Tags: decentralized-exchange, defi

If I go to DeFI exchanges (ex Uniswap) and I provide liquidity for small tokens which might be traded in one direction mostly. I wonder what would happen to my share of fees? Would I be losing money or making money?

As in the example below:
[image: CHI-USDC]

If I provide token ABC->DAI LP and then all ABC holders start selling it, do I lose my DAI? Some relevant sources would be helpful